# Force cascaded foreign key to activate delete trigger (mssql)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using a foreign key between table A->B.
A->child B->parent

When I delete a register from B, all children from A are deleted because a on delete cascade constraint I create. But, table A has a trigger on a AFTER DELETE condition.

The problem is that this trigger is not running when the constraint between A->B removes the A registers.

Can I force FK to activate that delete trigger?

(MS SQL 2008)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried the same scenario as you discussed(only name becomes reverse) above everything is working as expected. the table schema is

```
CREATE TABLE A(ID INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO A VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO A VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO A VALUES(3);
INSERT INTO A VALUES(4);
CREATE TABLE B(BID INT FOREIGN KEY(BID) REFERENCES A(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE);
INSERT INTO B VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO B VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO B VALUES(3);
INSERT INTO B VALUES(4);
```

and created a trigger as-

```
CREATE TRIGGER B_TRIGGER ON B
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('TRIGGER IS RUNNING AFTER DELETE OPERATION!', 16, 1);    
END
```

and when i delete a row from table A(i.e parent table) row that has same id from table B got deleted automatically because of cascade delete and trigger is also fired at the same time.

```
SQL Server Database Error: TRIGGER IS RUNNING AFTER DELETE OPERATION!   9   0
```

so i think there is no need to force the trigger externally.

Comment: Thanks. Could you try even FOR DELETE trigger, pls?

Comment: @user3168487 as i know FOR DELETE is not a trigger type in sql server.it has only AFTER Triggers,INSTEAD OF Triggers,CLR Triggers. so can you confirm it.